# Switching branches with IntelliJ & Git

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

this should be an easy one...

I'm trying IntelliJ (came from Eclipse) and I have this issue that I don't know how to handle, I have configured my project using the **branchA** no problems, but, as soon a try to checkout another branch **branchB** the IDE tells me that fails due some untracked file that will get overwrite.

The file is vcs.xml :S

If I delete it as the IDE recommends I lose the ability to switch branches.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or how do I have to configure the project so I can switch branches normally.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by " I lose the ability to switch branches."

Comment: I was talking about that when I manually delete the vcs.xml file the Git selector at the bottom right corner of the IDE disappeared. However, is fixed now. Thanks

Comment: at first, I find that strange. But on further consideration, I realize that particular file configures IntelliJ for version control integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to do two things

1) remove .idea/vcs.xml file from your Git repository

2) exclude it in .gitignore so you will not check this file in anymore. It is usually stored under /.idea/. This particular one can be done with

```
 .idea / vcs.xml
```

You should not check this file inside Git repository as the others suggest. Otherwise another IntelliJ user of the Git repo will overwrite his settings of vcs.

Comment: Thank you, I was approaching this way but I was forgetting adding it to the .gitignore

Comment: @WilliamAñez in fact you should ignore all files generated by IntelliJ. This includes the entire `.idea` folder and all `.iml` files.

Comment: Yes, that was I did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can go on VCS > Git > Commit. There you can toggle the unversioned file and toggle the checkbox, commit and your file is in the vcs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the untracked branch to git. From the command line it would be:

```
git add <file name>
git commit -m "Your message here"
```

In the IDE, find the file in the project tree-view, right-click, and select Git -> Add (or press Ctrl-Alt-A). Then to commit, Ctrl-K.